# How to save generated pdf in project folder Node Jasper Reports?

Tags: node.js, jasper-reports

I am using a library called [Node Jasper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jasper) . Pdf is also getting generated via dynamically passed parameters. I want to save that file in project folder. Can some one help me how to achieve that ? Below is the snipet

```
exports.jasperdemo = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    var report = {
        report: 'hw',
        data: {
            parameter1: req.body.parameter1,
            parameter2: req.body.parameter2
        },
    }
    var pdf = jasper.pdf(report);
    res.set({
        'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Length': pdf.length
    });
    fs.writeFile("Test.pdf",res.body);
    res.send(pdf)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a buffer of binary data using `new Buffer(pdf,"binary")` and pass it instead of res.body find the attached code

```
 exports.jasperdemo = (req, res, next) => {

        var report = {
            report: 'hw',
            data: {
                 parameter1: req.body.parameter1,
                 parameter2: req.body.parameter2
            }
        }

        var pdf = jasper.pdf(report);

        res.set({
            'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Length': pdf.length
        });

            fs.writeFile("./reports/Test.pdf",new Buffer(pdf, 'binary'), ()=>{
            console.log('successful');
        });
        res.send(pdf)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the directory before the file name in your `fs.writeFile()` function:

```
exports.jasperdemo = (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body)
        var report = {
            report: 'hw',
            data: {
                parameter1: req.body.parameter1,
                parameter2: req.body.parameter2
            },
        }
        var pdf = jasper.pdf(report);
        res.set({
            'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Length': pdf.length
        });
        // Added your change here
        fs.writeFile("./your/directory/Test.pdf",res.body);
        res.send(pdf)
    }
```

Comment: Brother now i can save the file in folder but now it is giving me this error - Error
Failed to load PDF document.

Comment: PDF is getting corrupted while generating

Comment: there is an error in your JSON at `data: {}` as in you have a comma after your last curly-brace, the engine thinks that there is going to be another attribute, but there is not.